# Assigning a variable = to any number between these two numbers

Tags: javascript

is there any way of assigning a variable lets say,

var between = any number between 5 and 10?

So when I call something like,

```
if(between === 6){
 //do this
}
```

it ends up being true and running the code?

Comment: Are you trying to generate a random integer between 5 and 10 or what? It's not clear to me if the question is about generating a number or comparing it.

Comment: `if (between > 5 && between < 10)`

Answer (score 2):

You would use two parts to a comparison.  There is no single operand in Javascript that checks for "betweenness".  You could build your own function to do that if you wanted.  Here's an `if` statement that requires two conditions to be true before the statement is true:

```
if (val >= 5 && val <= 10) {
    // val is between 5 and 10 (including both 5 and 10)
}
```

---

Or, you could build yourself a little function:

```
function isBetween(val, min, max) {
    return val >= min && val <= max;
}

if (isBetween(val, 5, 10)) {
    // val is between the two numbers
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer jQuery and have `between` numbers in the array, one of the way to solve this kind of task is by using [jQuery.inArray()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).

for example:

```
var between = [5,6,7,8,9,10];

if($.inArray(6, between)) {
     // do somethings
}
```

Comment: Or just without jQuery: `between.indexOf(6) > -1`.